# Scraping tweets via Python for specific hours of the day

Tags: python, twitter, web-scraping

I was wondering if someone could help me with modifying my current code for scraping tweets based on specific hours during each day. I'm currently using https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets-python to scrape tweets from more than 1 week ago. I downloaded all his files and pip installed all of the packages. I tried modifying to scrape tweets from 7:30-8:30pm(19:30-20:30) for each day from Nov 9th through Dec 7th and save those tweets in a csv. However, I cannot get it to scrape the tweets for me. This is how I modified the script:

```
import got
import csv
from unidecode import unidecode
import datetime

# Based on his docs, it looks like you need to do something like this
tweetCriteria = got.manager.TweetCriteria().setQuerySearch('Google').setSince("2016-11-09").setUntil("2016-12-07")
# All the tweets
print "Getting Tweets"
tweets = got.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweetCriteria)

BeginHour = 19
EndHour = 20
Minutes = 30

print "\nWriting CSV File"
n_written = 0
with open('tweets3.csv', 'w') as csvFile:
    TweetWriter = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=',')
    TweetWriter.writerow(['user','SentimentText','Date'])

    for tweet in tweets:
        if (tweet.date.hour > BeginHour and tweet.date.minute > Minutes) or \
       (tweet.date.hour < EndHour and tweet.date.minute < Minutes):
            user = unidecode(tweet.username)
            txt = unidecode(tweet.text)
            dt = tweet.date

            print "\nAdding Tweet to CSV File"
            TweetWriter.writerow([user, 0, txt, dt])
        
            n_written += 1
            print "There are now {} tweets in the CSV".format(n_written)
```

I'd greatly appreciate any help

Comment: how is `7:30pm - 8:30pm` equivalent to `21:30-22:30`?

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I'm not used the 24 hour clock. Either way I thought I don't know why it downloaded tweets from 11am-4pm

Answer (score 0):

Also you have a condition of `x > 10 or x < 12` which basically says if any one of those conditions is `True` then proceed. Therefore the condition will be true even for `15` since it is greater than `10`.

A better way to condition is to have

```
 for tweet in tweets:
     if (tweet.date.hour > BeginHour and tweet.date.minute > Minutes) and \
   (tweet.date.hour < EndHour and tweet.date.minute < Minutes):
```

rather than the `or`. You code could be doing anything depending on the data.

Comment: Thank you for you response. Unfortunately, now I can't get it to download tweets. Do you know how I could possibly fix this?